# How can I smoothly rotate a joint to an angle?

Tags: mathematics, box2d, physics

I would like to set the speed of my Box2D revolute joint on every update such that it rotates to a desired angle and stops. It should ramp down as its angle approaches the desired angle.

My first thought was just to set the speed to `+max` or `-max` based on the difference between the current angle and the desired angle. However, I think this might cause a see-saw effect as the joint overshoots its target angle.

**What torque should I apply (each tick) to a joint to achieve a rotation to a specific angle and then rest?**

Comment: Could you show us the code you've got so far, please?

Comment: Had a similar issue today and got it answered on another question. Feel free to check it out here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72348/how-do-i-lerp-between-values-that-loop-such-as-hue-or-rotation